# Converting Jackson JsonNode array to Java List<String>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I hava a Jackson JsonNode (v2.6.3) which has a json array as one of its fields and I'm looking to convert that array to a java List

Currently im doing the following problem is line 3:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonPayload();
JsonNode partial = jsonNode.path("someArrayField");
List<String> z = new ObjectMapper().readValue(partial.traverse(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){}); // <- this is the problem area
```

This feels expensive and improper I would have thought the library would provide a simple call to achieve this.

What would be the proper/efficient way of obtaining the List? I've seen a few others follow the same pattern as I did above but the answers are not widely accepted

Comment: Hello,

I think your code is okay. What is bothering you in the last line ?

Comment: @OresteViron it feels like im using the Library if you look at the methods available for JsonNode they have many convenience methods such as #asBoolean, #asDouble, #asText, etc. i would think there would be a simple way get a `List<String>` or even a `String[]`. But maybe im just looking for something that simply isnt there

Answer (score 3):

Since Jackson 2.11 methods `readerForListOf` and `readerForArrayOf` are available. Thus your code will look like the following:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonPayload();
JsonNode partial = jsonNode.path("someArrayField");
List<String> z = new ObjectMapper().readerForListOf(String.class).readValue(partial);
```